# Add jQuery conditional based on class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a conditional to my jQuery.
My script is:

```
$("#mycontent a.half.first"+$id).removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
$("#mycontent2 a.half.second"+$id).removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
```

I have a link in a table:

```
<table class='grav-results-table' id='mycontent' width='75%'>
  <tr class="grav-results-tr">
    <td class="grav-results-td">
    <a href="#inbound" class="half first3547" onclick="comtype(3547,'inbound', 704)">$184.20</a>
```

I'm trying to target the link shown above.  I've tried the following with different variations:

```
if ( $( "#mycontent" ).hasClass( "half first" ) ) {
  $("#mycontent a.half.first"+$id).removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
  $("#mycontent2 a.half.second"+$id).removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if ( $( this ).hasClass( "half first" ) )
```

This code is in the success area of my AJAX script.

But I can't seem to find the correct way to target the class.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mycontent` is the `ID` of your table which does not have a class of `half first` and it doesn't looks like you ever apply a `class` name to that element.

Comment: The documentation for jQuery [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) shows the parameter as a `className` ... "half first" is _two_ separate classes.  Should this be `if ( $( this ).hasClass( "half") && $( this ).hasClass( "first" ) )` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change you if condition to look for the class in the children of the table... like this:

```js
if ($("#mycontent").find("a.half").length > 0) {
  console.log('children found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='grav-results-table' id='mycontent' width='75%'>
  <tr class="grav-results-tr">
    <td class="grav-results-td">
      <a href="#inbound" class="half first3547"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The actual class is class="half first3547" (as an example.)  So I tried your example and: if ( $( "#mycontent" ).children().hasClass( "half" ) ) but even that does not recognize it either.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to use `find` as opposed to `children` since your a elements are not direct descendants of the table

Comment: It's still not finding it.  I did update my code in the question, because my tr and td both have classes assigned to them.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

TO add to Martin you can try this.

```
if ( $( "table#mycontent" ).children().hasClass( "half first" ) ) {
 alert("I have class in it.");
}
```

Comment: If I remove the conditional it works fine.  With the conditional, no luck.